# How to create a computed column in PrestoDB with values persisted?

Tags: sql, presto

I am working in PrestoDB to query and create tables to configure data in a way that I can draw upon it and work on it in Excel and PowerBI. I am trying to create a persisted calculated column that is simply the quotient of two other existing columns.

A colleague suggested

```
Create Table B as 
Select * , Column A/Column B as Column Q
from Table A
```

however when I perform

```
Select * 
from Table B
```

column Q is there but completely empty.

What can I run to permanently add these computed columns so that when I query this data the values are persisted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PrestoDB supports computed columns, much less persisted computed columns.

I think what you want is *view*, though, not a table:

```
create view v_a 
    select a.*, ColumnA/ColumnB as ColumnQ
    from A a;
```

Anyone who queries `v_b` will see `ColumnQ` with the latest calculation of the ratio.